# After message type e, program doesn't return to selection-screen ABAP

Tags: abap, sap-selection-screens

I'm trying to use a message type E in my report. The thing is that when the message is triggered, the program doesn't return to the selection-screen. Can anyone help me? Here's the code I use to achieve this:

```
IF rb_tri IS NOT INITIAL AND p_trim-low IS INITIAL.

  MESSAGE e038.

ENDIF.
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide a complete example. In the code you provide, no E message is triggered at all. Also, the behavior of the MESSAGE statement depends heavily on the program block it is called from.

Comment: Sorry, I shouls be written MESSAGE e038, not w038.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I combine your question with [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11844518/676874) I offer another solution:

Don't make your test after starting the process (`START-OF-SELECTION`) but on the selection screen:

```
PARAMETER: p_test.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN.
  IF p_test IS INITIAL.
    MESSAGE e038(00).
  ENDIF.
```

The E-message blocks the selection screen until the problem is solved.

Comment: Yes.  This is how selection-screen validation should happen.  Better yet, if possible put it in the event AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON P_TEST or similar.

Answer (score 6):

I found the aswer. I should have used a S message and display it like a E type message. To get back to the selection-screen I had to use LEAVE LIST_PRECESSING. The code is below:

```
START-OF-SELECTION.

IF rb_tri IS NOT INITIAL AND p_trim-low IS INITIAL.

  MESSAGE s038 DISPLAY LIKE 'E'.
  Leave list-processing.

ENDIF.
```

Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
Message text-001 TYPE 'S' Display LIKE 'E'
```

or

```
At selection screen on radiobutton group rad1.
  if condition
    message text-001 type 'I' display like 'E'.
    set screen 1000.
    leave screen.
  endif
```