# Error message is displayed not on selection screen

Tags: report, abap, sap-selection-screens

I have to display error message on the selection screen if data was not found, and I have to display this message directly on the selection screen. My problem is that it's displayed on blank screen.
This is my code:

```
FORM 1main .
  CLEAR: gt_tbalv.
  PERFORM check_screen.
  PERFORM get_data.
  IF gt_tbalv IS NOT INITIAL.
    CALL SCREEN 100.
  ELSE.
*   Message Data not found
    MESSAGE e010 DISPLAY LIKE 'S'.
  ENDIF.
ENDFORM.                    " 1MAIN
```

Where is my mistake?

PS: I call this form from START OF SELECTION  event of selection screen

```
************************************************************************
***                       START-OF-SELECTION                         ***
************************************************************************
START-OF-SELECTION.
  PERFORM 1main.
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example - no use guessing where you are calling that FORM from...

Answer (score 3):

I assume you call this form in START-OF-SELECTION. You should use AT SELECTION-SCREEN instead.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832700/after-message-type-e-program-doesnt-return-to-selection-screen-abap) for an example.

Comment: You have right that i call it there, but i correct this another way, i call the message like that  MESSAGE s010 DISPLAY LIKE 'E'. and all is good

Answer (score 0):

You can you a message type 'S' and display like 'E'. After the message use the  LEAVE TO LIST-PROCESSING, so your program will be interrupted.